# Using a service reference to distribute classes instead of locally stored ones

Tags: c#, wcf, uwp, service-reference

Im writing a UWP app and was having a think about how to cascade changes more easily without the need to manually update each file.

Right now I have a WCF application with a bunch of classes. My UWP app also has the exact same classes and when I download the data i litterally "swap" them over.

Is using the WCF applications service reference to the ones stored on there a viable option so instead of having 2 sets of identical files, all it needs to do instead is `ServiceReference.ClassName` and then go about its merry way. It strikes me that in the event changes need to be made, if the classes only need changing on the service and then the reference updating on the UWP app then it would save time/space/effort?

Are there downsides to relying on a setup like that?

Comment: Why don't you have a shared contract assembly instead of relying on you remembering to press update in your IDE?

Comment: @nvoigt That would be down to my rookie status when it comes to all of this. It only occured to me now that i could even share the reference in the first place (5 months later >.<) And now it finally dawns on me what a WCF class library is for.....

Comment: You should avoid using the generated service reference. You can call a service directly by using ChannelFactory<T>.